# bash clustering data from one column and extracting its values from other

Tags: python, bash

I have a small problem where I have four columns from apache logs like so:

```
1   45      2525        2001-01-09 03:51:09
2   25      4000        2001-01-09 05:54:20
3   87      5500        2001-01-09 05:04:09
4   76      4000        2001-01-09 05:08:43
5   345     2525        2001-01-09 05:11:33
6   875     5500        2001-01-09 05:28:23
7   2345    2525        2001-01-09 05:32:13
8   1445    4000        2001-01-09 05:40:55
9   69      2525        2001-01-09 05:41:33
```

what I want to do is cluster items on column 3 taking column 2 into account. So, I would like the end result look like so:

```
45,345,2345,69      2525
25,1445             4000
87,875              5500
```

How do I go about doing this in bash? or any other command line tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with awk:

With the ternary operator from Aarons comment to get rid of leading commas:

```
awk '{cluster[$3] = cluster[$3] ? cluster[$3]","$2 : $2} END {for(x in cluster){print cluster[x]"\t"x}}'
```

Comment: that seems to work like a charm.. for some reason it starts with a `,` on each row - would you know why? Apologies, I am no `awk` expert.

Comment: You can use a ternary to avoid the leading comma : `awk '{cluster[$3] = cluster[$3] ? cluster[$3]","$2 : $2} END {for(x in cluster){print cluster[x]"\t"x}}'`. Also you can add `| column -t` after it to obtain a properly tabulated table as in your sample output

Comment: using the ternary does seem to avoid the comma - thank you for that. However, when I try the `column -t`, it seems to hang? So, I do `cat mytext.csv | <awk_here> | column -t >out.txt` I had to kill it.. Any ideas?

Comment: Well how do you determine its hanging? How large is your logfile? Depending on the size it might take some minutes to process. Also you can skip the `cat ...` and just do `awk '...' mytext.csv `

Comment: @voiDnyx what I meant was without the `column -t` it processes in seconds (and the results are spoton), whereas when I use `column -t` it seems to run for a bit (so I killed it).